# javascript Open gmail and signin automaticly

Tags: javascript, html, gmail

I'm just building an experimental personal site where I could log myself into gmail with the press of a button.

Everithing goes fine, when I manually go to the gmail site and type the javascript command into the url line like this and press enter:

```
javascript: document.getElementsByName('Email').item(0).value='name'; document.getElementsByName('Passwd').item(0).value='password'; document.getElementsByName('signIn').item(0).click(); void(0);
```

But when I try to do the same from a page, nothing happens... Can someone please help me out?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />

        <title>Test</title>

        <script>
            var name = 'name';

            function login(url1) {

                win = window.open(url1, nome);

                win.document.getElementsByName('Email').item(0).value='name';
                win.document.getElementsByName('Passwd').item(0).value='password';
                win.document.getElementsByName('signIn').item(0).click(); void(0); 
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <button id="buton1" onclick="login('https://accounts.google.com')">GMAIL LOGIN</button>
    </body>

</html>
```

I've checked a lot of forums and answers, and it seemed that this method should work, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Now imagine that your code was followed by similar code that would send lots of spam to people using your GMail account.

Cross domain DOM manipulation is forbidden by browsers as it would be a huge security hole.

The exception is [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage), but that requires the cooperation of both sites.

You need a browser extension for this sort of thing.

Comment: Ok, I see the point. Is there maybe some other way to do what I'm trying to do (signin on button click) or is this a general no-go on all websites (forums, social, etc.) not just gmail?

Comment: CSRF attacks are sometimes a possibility, but Google defend against them. You need a browser extension.